# Tests failing in Capybara Webkit driver which work in Selenium Driver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, integration-testing, capybara-webkit

I have the following rspec test which works fine in the default Selenium driver but it fails in the [Capybara Webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit) driver.

When the Sign Up button is clicked it verifies the credit card is valid using the payment gateway and before sending the form to the server. It seems like it is not sending the ajax request to the payment gateway in the headless mode. How could I fix this for the webkit driver as I know the code is correct as the same test passes in Selenium.

```
it "Subscribe to Plan", js: true do
  visit subscription_plans_path
  fill_in "user_email", :with => subscription_user_email
  fill_in "user_password", :with => "password"
  fill_in "Name", :with => "John Doe"
  fill_in "new_credit_card_field", :with => "4242424242424242"
  fill_in "security_code", :with => "123"
  select (Time.zone.now.year + 1), :from => "date_year"
  click_button "Sign up"

  page.should have_content('Dashboard')
end
```

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question without more context. The specific failure message you receive from your test would be a good place to start.

Comment: It fails here: page.should have_content('Dashboard')  
The reason for the failure is because when you click Sign Up it should make an ajax request to the payment gateway verify the credit card and then submit the form to the server and when the form is submitted they should go to the dashboard where I verify that on the page there should be content text Dashboard. I checked the test db and it doesnt even submit the form because the external ajax request is blocked probably in the headless mode.

Comment: The reason is likely because the ajax request isn't complete by the time you make the assertion. See here: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara

Comment: If you run using `:webkit_debug` as your driver instead of `:webkit`, it will print the commands and results of the driver, which should clarify how it's interacting with the external service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to use Selenium drivers instead of using Webkit driver for javascript related tests.